# Why Does My Class Constructor Not Work As Expected?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I've been having a little difficulty with my personal project. See full code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Player {
public:
Player(string name, int Dex, int Mod, int Lvl, int diceRoll);

int calcInitiative(int Dex, int Mod, int Lvl);
int sortInitiative(int Init);

int diceRoll;

private:

int mDex, mMod, mLvl;
string mName;
};

int main() {

Player::Player(string name, int Dex, int Mod, int Lvl, int diceRoll) {
mName(name), mDex(Dex), mMod(Mod), mLvl(Lvl);
}

Player D("Derek", 2, 0, 6, rollD);

return 0;
}
```

The issue is the constructor definition in main. The error tells me "type name is not allowed", which seems to mean that's it identifying the variable "name" as a type but not the string, despite my inclusion of the appropriate libraries.

Can anyone offer any advice as to how I can fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are putting the constructor definition inside of `main()`. That's illegal. You should put it at namespace scope.

Also notice, that you are also using some wrong syntax for the [constructor initialization list](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html):

```
Player::Player(string name, int Dex, int Mod, int Lvl, int diceRoll) 
    : mName(name), mDex(Dex), mMod(Mod), mLvl(Lvl)
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//  This is how you should write the initialization list
{
}

int main() {
    Player D("Derek", 2, 0, 6, rollD);
    return 0;
}
```

Moreover, you haven't declared `rollD` anywhere, so the compiler will emit an error for this after you fix the ones I mentioned above.

Finally, please keep in mind that having `using` directives such as this:

```
using namespace std;
```

At namespace scope is regarded as a bad programming practice, because it easily leads to name clashes with entities that belong to the `std` namespace.

Comment: Ahh, whoops! I wanted to define it besides in-line since eventually it will be pretty complex, but I forgot it couldn't be within main. Thank you! Correction on initialization list with reference was also very helpful!

Answer (score 4):

You can't define functions (including constructor) inside another function. Simply move the definition in global scope or define it inline in class definition.